Corollary 13.15 of Jech's Set Theory
From Jech's Set Theory:

Lemma 13.14. The function $\alpha\mapsto L_\alpha$ is $\Delta_1$.
Corollary 13.15. The property "$x$ is constructible" is absolute for inner models of ZF.
Proof: let $M$ be an inner model of ZF. Since $M\supseteq \text{Ord}$ we have for all $x\in M$
$$(x\text{ is constructible})^M \iff \exists \alpha\in M (x\in L^M_\alpha) \iff \exists \alpha(x\in L_\alpha)\iff x \text{ is constructible}.$$

I understand why $\exists \alpha\in M$ is equivalent to $\exists \alpha$. What I do not see is why $x\in L^M_\alpha$ is equivalent to $x\in L_\alpha$. I'm guessing here is where the Lemma is used, yet I cannot see how the Lemma implies the result.

Yes, that's where the lemma is used. $\Delta_1$ things are absolute for transitive models ($\Sigma_1$ things are absolute outward and $\Pi_1$ things are absolute inward). Surely this is in the book somewhere, but if not, it's easy to prove using the fact that $\Delta_0$ things are absolute.
Note however that this doesn't imply "$x$ is constructible" is absolute for transitive models... the proof also uses the fact that inner models contain all of the ordinals, not just that they're transitive.

I had only skimmed through the section on the Levy Hierarchy because I could not understand it properly: in particular, it is my understanding that a formula with free variables is equivalent to its unviersal closure (e.g. $x\in y$ is equivalent to $\forall x\forall y (x\in y)$). If that is so, then shoudln't, for example, $\prod_1$ be empty? If $\Phi\in\prod_1$, then $\Phi = \forall x_1\ldots\forall x_n \phi$ for $\phi\in \sum_0 = \prod_0$, yet $\Phi$ is then equivalent to $\phi$, so we consider $\Phi$ a $\prod_0$, not $\prod_1$ formula.

@Sam That's like saying "x is a prime number" is equivalent to "all numbers are prime". What you're probably thinking about is that there is often the convention that assigning truth (or provability) of an open formula where $x$ is 'arbitrary' is means the same thing as truth/ provability the universal closure. I wouldn't call that an equivalence, and it's certainly not the appropriate notion of equivalence of formulas here, which would be that $\forall \vec x (\varphi(\vec x)\leftrightarrow \psi(\vec x))$ is provable/true in the relevant context.

@Sam Like it's certainly not the case that one can prove "for every $x$, $x$ is a prime number if and only if every number is prime". An example of a $\Pi_1$ formula that is not $\Delta_0$ or $\Delta_1$ would be "$x=P(\omega)$", since going to a larger transitive model $M'\supset M$, one can have $P(\omega)^M=M\cap P(\omega)\subsetneq M'\cap P(\omega)=P(\omega)^{M'}$

We say here two formulas $\phi(\vec{x})$ and $\psi(\vec{y})$ are equivalent iff they have the same number of free variables and $\forall \vec{x} (\phi(\vec{x}) \iff \psi(\vec{x}))$?

@Sam There are a number of conventions one could follow... for instance it could be good or bad to say that $x_1\in x_2$ is equivalent to $x_1\in x_2\land x_3=x_3.$ The details don't matter too much in this case, but I wouldn't allow substitutions, as you seem to be doing, since that could lead to undesirable things like $x_1\in x_2$ being equivalent to $x_2\in x_1$.
